# Importing an Excel spreadsheet into C# forms in a Array format?

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, excel, import

I'm trying to import an excel spreadsheet with names and phone numbers of people (350+), and can't figure out how I would go about putting those names and numbers into a array to use them separately into text boxes to edit them, delete them, move to different files and such.. Any help would be greatly help full on my quest!

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

For a similar project I used [linqtoexcel](https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/). This framework allows you to query an excel spreadsheet using the LINQ syntax which allows you to access all the normal LINQ methods.

So you could do something like this:

```
var excelSheet = new ExcelQueryFactory(tempFilePath);
var results = (from x in excelSheet.Worksheet()
                  select x).ToArray();
```

Where `tempFilePath` would be an excel file.

Answer (score 0):

To import information from Excel there are a few ways of going about this. The simplest is to add a reference to Microsoft Excel Object Library via `Add Reference -> COM`. From there you can add create an excel Application and instance to access the Excel Document:

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Open("Workbook Path Goes Here");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oSheet = oBook.Worksheets["Sheet Name Goes here"];
```

From here you can grab the cells you need and extract the information from them. You may want to define a `Struct` or `Class` to store the information in:

```
    public class Contact
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in your main part of the code just create a list of contacts:

```
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
```

Now you can freely add to the list as you iterate through your Excel spreadsheet.